# Maintain session in subdomain

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis-7

I have one url *www.myexample.in*. One of my pages navigates to a new subdomain *test.myexample.in*. On the *default.aspx* page of my subdomain I have a check for my session which i created in my parent domain (www.myexample.in). Now when page of subdomain is opened no such session value is found and `session["employeeid"]` becomes blank , earlier in which I put my employeeId.

In Parent domain I created

```
session["employeeid"]="1233";
```

Now on opening the subdomain page from my project I get blank value

```
string EmployeeId =  Convert.ToString(session["employeeid"]);
//EmployeeId is blank here
```

Please tell me how to pass my `session["employeeid"]` with value to my subdomain. I am using State server in Web config

Answer (score 0):

add following config setting in `web.config`

```
<httpCookies domain=".myexample.in"/>
```